# Unit Testing framework for Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Do we have any Unit Testing framework for Kendo UI/ Kendo Grid? What would be the best framework for testing the Kendo UI? My Application has lot of Kendo UI stuff and jQuery. Looking for a good Unit Testing framework for this.

I saw a couple of frameworks which support Unit testing for Angular but nothing for Kendo. Also I can see that the IDE plug-in is not available for most of them. Could someone please suggest a good framework which would meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate testing framework for kendo ui.  Jasmine would probably be your best (and most common) choice.
It is framework agnostic and has many great features that make testing easy.
Here is a blog post that shows a nice example: http://blog.falafel.com/unit-testing-kendo-ui-datasources-with-jasmine-and-mockjax/